# How can I take values a user selects from a sample?

Tags: r, sample, dice

I have a sample of dice rolls given by "Rolls<-sample(1:6, 5, replace=TRUE)"

What I want to do is be able to do is ask a user to select two values from the sample, then I want the two values to be added and be stored in the sample as well. (I don't need anything to happen to the values that were used in the addition)

My main issue with this is that I've been using:

"first_number <- readline(prompt="Please enter the first value you'd like to add: ")" (and the same for "second_number")

and this doesn't ensure that the value they choose is within the sample I have.

For example, let's say my sample is 4 5 6 6 2, with the code I'm currently using the user is able to select any value, such as 1, 0, or even 200, even though none of these are in the sample set given. If I could fix this then the rest of what I'm trying to do will be simple.

Any support would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```r
#Rolls <- c( 4,5,6,6,2 )

set.seed(100)
Rolls<-sample(1:6, 5, replace=TRUE)
chosen <- c()
ordinals <- c("first","second")

while( length(chosen) < 2 ) {

    cat( "Dice = ",Rolls, "\n" )

    pick <- readline(
        prompt=paste("Please enter the", ordinals[length(chosen)+1],"value you'd like to add: ")
    )

    if( pick %in% Rolls ) {
        chosen <- append( chosen, as.numeric(pick) )
        Rolls <- Rolls[ -match( pick, Rolls ) ]
    } else {
        cat("Whoops, that's not a valid choice!\n")
    }

}
```

Looks like this in my session:

```
Dice =  2 6 3 1 2 
Please enter the first value you'd like to add: 4
Whoops, that's not a valid choice!
Dice =  2 6 3 1 2 
Please enter the first value you'd like to add: 2
Dice =  6 3 1 2 
Please enter the second value you'd like to add: 5
Whoops, that's not a valid choice!
Dice =  6 3 1 2 
Please enter the second value you'd like to add: 3
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good, only thing is your code starts with setting the Rolls as a certain set of numbers (the numbers i gave as an example) however, in my code the numbers are randomly generated by the "sample" function, would this still work if the first line was instead "Rolls<-sample(1:6, 5, replace=TRUE)"?

Comment: I'm asking this because this code is part of a function I'm making for a board game, so there are going to be many rolls and many samples, so defining Rolls as you have (with numbers that aren't randomly generated) won't work for me

Comment: Yes, replace that with your code to perform the roll

Comment: np! I updated to reflect this (should have done it in the first place)

Comment: sorry one more thing, where do the values the user picks get stored? I can see the first one gets stored in "pick", where does the second choice get stored? Or does it store both in "pick"?

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now, they get stored in "chosen"

Comment: yup, I don't store the value until its verified that its a valid choice.

Comment: This is a bit of extra work I'd like to do to the code but since you've been so helpful so far I might as well ask you; I'm using this code to take the two values a user selects, I'm then adding them up (using "new_number<- sum(chosen)") and adding it to my sample (using "Rolls<-c(Rolls,new_number)"), however, how do i then remove the values in "chosen" from my sample. Basically, after the user selects the values and I add them up, I want them out of the sample, is that something simple or does it require hefty coding?

Comment: It's already there! Rolls is being emptied for every pick the user makes, check `Rolls` when my code is done, it should be short of the two numbers chosen. Just go ahead and add the sum as you propsed in the last comment.

Comment: Oh my, you're right, I was just being blind don't mind me. Thank you so much for all the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to control that logic yourself. Try this function:

```r
readline_int <- function(..., lo = -Inf, hi = Inf, maxtries = 10) {
  ans <- as.numeric(readline(...))
  while (maxtries > 0 && (anyNA(ans) || ans < lo || ans > hi)) {
    warning("value not within expected bounds: [", lo, ",", hi, "]")
    maxtries <- maxtries - 1
    ans <- as.numeric(readline(...))
  }
  ans
}

readline_int(prompt="Please enter the first value you'd like to add: ", lo=1, hi=6)
# Please enter the first value you'd like to add: 9
# Warning in readline_int(prompt = "Please enter the first value you'd like to add: ",  :
#   value not within expected bounds: [1,6]
# Please enter the first value you'd like to add: 5
# [1] 5
```